# How to Save a Word File in the Current Destination instead of the Documents folder?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

My PowerShell script opens the My_Paper.doc file, applies font, and then saves it as My_Paper.docx.

The issue is the docx is being saved in the Documents folder instead of the current destination, which is `C:\Place\`.

What is the fix for this?

```
$Filename = 'C:\Place\My_Paper.doc'

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $False #$True makes Word Open
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open($Filename)

$Selection = $word.Selection
$Document.Select()
$Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
$Selection.Font.Size = 12

# This saves to the Documents folder
$Report = 'My_Paper.docx'
$Document.SaveAs([ref]$Report, [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocument)
$Document.Close()
$Word.Quit()
```

Comment: Include the wanted path in the filename: `$Report = 'C:\Place\My_Paper.docx'`. Also, don't forget to release used Com objects after quitting Word: `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Word COM object uses a different working directory than your PowerShell script, so you need to specify the full path if you want to save the file elsewhere. Use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#pwd) `$PWD` for getting the path to the current working directory of your script.

```
$Report = Join-Path $PWD.Path 'My_Paper.docx'
```